# Execution problem with button and trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, execution

I would admit that I'm not a pro at all, I just try to do some app script for my company and I faced a problem I really don't understand.

I can't execute a function I've made with a button nor with a trigger, but only by doing by my own with the execute button in the app script interface.

The issue is always the same :

> Error The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

But as I said above, when I execute by myself I don't receive any error message and the code works well.

Here is the code :

```
function Colle() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1;
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data GC'), true);
   spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate
   spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data GC").getRange('A1:F500').activate(); // I know that my 
       //data will never exceed more than 400 so just as a security I've put 500
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sauvegarde GC'), true);
   spreadsheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).activate();
   spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data GC").getRange('A1:F500').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
   SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
   SuppDoubl(); //Delete the duplicates
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sauvegarde GC'), true);
   spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
 };
```

*Sorry for my English

```
function SuppDoubl() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A:F').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().removeDuplicates().activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
```

Comment: Could you show the function `SuppDoubl()`? And where exactly the error appears? Can you tell the line number?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, the script for SuppDoubl is based on the removeDupplicates function in app script here it is :                                                                                     function SuppDoubl() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:F').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().removeDuplicates().activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};

Comment: This seems like a lot of code and can probably be simplified a lot (or made differently). Doing that should also fix the issue. Could you explain the result you are pursuing? What is the script supposed to do?

Comment: I've solved the problem by simplifiying the code, thanks for your interest. The script is copying data from a sheet to another and take the last row in order not to erase the previous data. It aims to save my data.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need so many `activate()`s? If you want just to copy some range from one sheet to other sheet it can be done without `activate()`:

```
function colle() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Data GC').getRange('A1:F500');
  var target = ss.getSheetByName('Sauvegarde GC').getRange('A1'); // or A + last row
  source.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  // SuppDoubl(); // <-- probably the error is here?

  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sauvegarde GC'), true);
  ss.getRange('A1').activate();
}
```

It works fine for me (without the `SupDoubl()`) via button and any way.

Comment: Usually a script having many `activate()` methods are the result of the use of the macro recorder. Some users take those scripts examples to  create new scripts.

Comment: Rubén is right, I used a macro and then managed it to have my script.

Comment: I've tried with your script. The same problem stays even without the SupDoubl() which works with removeDupplicate(), with the button and the trigger : The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

Comment: Alas. I can't reproduce the problem on my test sheet with test data. Perhaps your data has something special. Or there is some typo in your code. For example, I had the similar error once when I tried to define a range in similar way: getRange('A' + n) and it turned out that the 'n' was a string and there was A1, then A12, then A123, then A1234... etc and it escalated quickly (instead A1, A2, A3, A4...).